# Regex filter excludes ":" and includes at least one word character

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

The task is to exclude value if one contains **:**. The value also must include at least 1 word character.

matched string values are:

```
'   h-73 \r\n\t'
'   hey'
'hi  '
'7'
```

not matched values are:

```
'    \r\n\t' // neither letter not digit
'    ' // neither letter not digit
'  sds:  \r\n\t' // :
```

To exclude **:** I'd use `/^[^:]+$/` to filter word characters I'd use `/\w+/`.

I have no idea how to use them together in the same regex because scope of each condition should be whole string.

Comment: Why not use two regexes instead of one, and combine the results using `&&`? And "includes `:`" can even be done without a regex.

Comment: _"`'    \m\n\t'` // neither letter not digit"_ - what about `m`, is that not a letter? `\m` is not an escape sequence for any kind of special character, but just the characters backslash and m.

Comment: That is a typo (fixed now), OP uses `\r\n\t` in all examples to show whitespace usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex that matches your specifications is

```js
/^[^\w:]*\w[^:]*$/
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^\w:]*` - zero or more chars other than word and `:` chars
- `\w` - one word char
- `[^:]*` - any chars, zero or more occurrences, other than a colon
- `$` - end of string.

JavaScript demo:

```js
const texts = ['   h-73 \r\n\t','   hey','hi  ','7','    \r\n\t','    ','  sds:  \r\n\t'];
const re  = /^[^\w:]*\w[^:]*$/;
for (const text of texts) {
    console.log("'"+text+"'", '=>', re.test(text));
}
```

**NOTE**: You could also use `/^[^:]*\w[^:]*$/`, but this regex grabs non-colons from the start of string as many times as possible, and then backtracks to find a word char, which is less efficient. So, the `\w` in the first negated character class is welcome.